# SignalR Access to fetch has been blocked by CORS

Tags: c#, asp.net, cors, signalr

I am currently following [this basic signal R tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?tabs=visual-studio&view=aspnetcore-5.0).
But because I want to use it in an existing project I split it up. The Hub is inside a different project than the client. Therefore the IP address is different. Inside the configuration of the Hub I of course enabled cors:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
                    services.AddCors();
                    services.AddControllers();
                    services.AddSignalR();
                    //other configuration code
    }
    
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env){
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(x => x
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .AllowAnyOrigin()
        );

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapHub<LiveUpdating.ChatHub>("/chatHub");
        });
    }
```

However when I now try to connect to the chatHub in my client (setup is exactly the same as in the link above except that I changed the connection to `var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("https://localhost:44316/chatHub").build();` ) I get this error:

```
     Access to fetch at 'https://localhost:44316/chatHub/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1' from 
     origin 'https://localhost:44341' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight 
     request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 
     header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode 
     is 'include'.
```

Shouldn't this normally work, when I add the app.UseCors as seen above. Because for all my other Rest Controllers it works fine.

Comment: Have you tried adding `.AllowCredentials()` to your policy?

Comment: Completely forgot about that one, thanks. It Works but I have to replace  .AllowAnyOrigin() with   .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true) to still allow anyOrigin

Answer (score 7):

Replacing the app.useCors with

```
            app.UseCors(x => x
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader()
           .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin => true)
           .AllowCredentials());
```

fixes the bug